# How can I fix this python socket problem? (solved)

Tags: python, sockets

I've been trying to create a chat room using python and the socket module, but I have run into a bug which I don't know how to fix.

[image]

At the moment, when I send a message through one of the clients, the message will be outputted again in the terminal of the person who sent it. E.g. column 3, rows 1 & 3 (column 3 is Jim's).

This is the code I wrote for the clients (Re. receiving/sending data):

```
# Receive data from server
def receive_data():
    while True:
        try:
            mes = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            # If the message is 'name', send name to server
            if mes == 'name':
                client.send(name.encode('ascii'))
            # If the message comes from the same person, don't show it
            elif name == mes[0:(len(name)+1)]:
                pass
            # Otherwise it will print the message
            else:
                print(mes)
        except:
            # Close the connection
            print(f"{colours.Colours.red}An error occurred!{colours.Colours.end}")
            client.close()
            break

# Send data to server
def send_data():
    while True:
        message_to_send = input("You : ")
        mes = f"\n{name} : {message_to_send}"
        client.send(mes.encode('ascii'))
```

I wrote this for the server. After it was all setup, the receive function was run. By the way, the protocol is TCP.

```
# Handling clients
def handle_clients(client):
    while True:
        try:
            # Broadcasting messages
            mes = client.recv(1024)
            broadcast(mes)
        except:
            # Removing clients
            name = clients[client]
            broadcast(f"{colours.Colours.red}{name} has left!{colours.Colours.end}".encode('ascii'))
            del clients[client]
            break

# Recieving data
def recieve():
    while True:
        # Accept connection
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        print(f"{colours.Colours.green}Connected with {addr}!{colours.Colours.end}")

        # Request & store name
        conn.send("NAME".encode('ascii'))
        name = conn.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
        clients.update({conn : name})

        # Start handling thread for client
        thread = threading.Thread(target=handle_clients, args=(conn,))
        thread.start()
```

How can I solve this?

Sam

**SOLVED**
After going over it a bit, I figured out what the problem was. It was more about the server relaying it, instead of the client.

This is my new server code (that I changed):

```
# If the name of the sender is the same as in the message, return True
def check_name(name, client_name):
    client_name = client_name[0]
    if name == client_name:
        return True
    else:
        return False

# Send message to all clients
def broadcast(message, ignore=False):
    for client, name in clients.items():
        if not ignore:
            client.send(message.encode('ascii'))
        else:    
            if check_name(ignore, name):
                pass
            else:
                client.send(message.encode('ascii'))

# Handling clients
def handle_clients(client):
    while True:
        try:
            # Decode message
            mes = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            if not mes:
                break
            
            # Get the name of the sender
            name = mes.split(" : ")
            name = name[0]
            name = name.replace('\n', '')
            name = name.strip()
            mes = mes.replace('\n', '')

            # Broadcast
            broadcast(mes, ignore=name)
        except:
            # Removing clients
            name = clients[client]
            broadcast(f"{colours.Colours.red}{name} has left!{colours.Colours.end}".encode('ascii'))
            del clients[client]
            break
```

This is my new client code:

```
# Recieve data from server
def receive():
    while True:
        try:
            mes = client.recv(1024).decode('ascii')
            # If the message is 'NAME', send the name to server
            if mes == 'NAME':
                client.send(name.encode('ascii'))
            # Otherwise it will print the message
            else:
                print(mes)
        except:
            # Close the connection
            print(f"{colours.Colours.red}An error occurred!{colours.Colours.end}")
            client.close()
            break

# Send data to server
def send():
    while True:
        message_to_send = input("You : ")
        mes = f"\n{name} : {message_to_send}"
        client.send(mes.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: It looks like you added an `if` statement to try to avoid printing your own message. Apparently the if statement isn't working. I suggest you debug your code to figure out why. [This article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) gives some great tips to get you started.

Comment: This part: `name == mes[0:(len(name)+1)]` <- doesn't work. Can you figure out why not?